# Placing a label in an EditText with specific design

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I need to rewrite an iOS app for Android. The layout should look alike and I struggle with this issue:

I want to have a label on the left side of an EditText. It should stick there and don't let the EditText text overwrite the label:

[image: Label for EditText]

I have tried using the interface builder in Android Studio like this : 
[image]

The problem is, that the EditText's text does not hide behind the label.
Any ideas?

**Edit:**
Since my question was unclear:

I want a label inside an EditText.
It should stick to the left and have a margin to the input of EditText.

Comment: can you rephrase your question it is unclear to understand.

Comment: @KaranMer is it more clear now? If not, which part is unclear?

Comment: you want label that will just stick out there next to your password field. correct?

Comment: A TextView overlapping your EditText might do the job, no ?

Comment: @KaranMer correct - as vincrichaud says it should be overlapping. But when I tried (see picture 2) it was not correct.

Comment: why you need a label inside an edittext??? you can place a textview and edittext side-by-side and achieve the above design

Comment: overlapping your views will cause your edtitext text to go below your label, do you want that?

Comment: I don't think you need to overlap your views, just put your ``TextView`` on the left and your ``EditText`` to ``match_parent``, why overlap? ``EditText`` will hide overflow content as if the ``TextView`` was over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below code in your xml and check, this will align your label text with password field where user can enter the password.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding_medium">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/label"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:text="Password"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_medium"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_xsmall"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_xsmall"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"/>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/label"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Note: I have used androidx controls as I am using new material design library. If you are using support library you would need to replace them with controls from support library.**

Comment: Yes, I had to change to the support library, but it works like a charm - thanks